# How can I add an extension to Wordpress Categories Permalink?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I've got Permalinks for my posts like /uncategorized/sample-post.html.

I've also got Permalinks for Pages such as /sample-page.html.

I can't work out how to add this to categories and tags. Does anyone have any advice how to do this?

Connor

Comment: Welcome to SO, a Q&A site about programming. You're merely asking a question about a specific product and how to use it. May I suggest you the [wordpress support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/) as it seems more fitting for your support issue?

Comment: In addition to the suggestion made by @hakra you might consider posting your question (after searching for it first!) on the [Wordpress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) section of SE.

Answer (score 1):

From Admin area>Posts>Categories
From Admin area>Posts>Tages

Comment: I mean so that instead of mysite.com/category/uncategorized/, I could have mysite.com/category/uncategorized.html.